# \newcommand does and does not work in titles

Tags: bug, mathjax, titles, newcommand

\newcommand within a question has in my experience failed to work in titles.

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2339764/counterexamples-to-thk-1-cap-k-2-subseteq-thk-1-cup-thk-2-and-mod) when I hit "reload", I see the backslash and Th in red; i.e. it doesn't work. But when I click on "edit" and then "save", then it does work. This can mislead people who edit questions.

Comment: If anyone is confused by this, the reason for the difference in behaviour is that when you use $\newcommand$ while editing it loads the macros into memory and when you add new mathjax to the page it remembers those macros. When you reload the page it clears those macros and new macros only effect elements on the page below where they are defined.

Comment: @T.Gunn : This leaves the question of whether there is any reasonable way to edit the title of that question that does not violate the rule agains using more than 150 characters.

Comment: One could accept the slight inelegance of $Th(K_1)$ and $Mod(K_1)$. One could use Unicode. One could chose a different title altogether. Seem all more or less reasonable. Though Unicode is maybe too much of a hassle.

Comment: Even of it did, it won't be a good idea, since these commands are not defined for the front page, or search results, or user profiles.

Comment: I edited the page so that the subject line says Th$(K_1)$ and Mod$(K_1),$ with "Th" and "Mod" not in MathJax at all.